Teach high school computer science without a credential
I am about to finish my MS in CS and I also have a BS in CS from a relatively well-known school, have a lot of experience TA-ing (grading, leading discussion sections, one on one help, some lecturing), and would love to teach at the high school level.
However, I don't think I can afford a credential. I know the answers to these are often very state specific, but I don't have a particular state in mind and would be happy to move (within the US), so any answers about any state would be great.
What would be the best pathway for this? It seems that a lot of alternate certification routes are for other STEM subjects like math and science. An alternative is that I could teach in a private or charter school. Would this be foolish, considering my lack of high school experience? As a side note, I don't think I have the necessary experience for a CTE credential.
How competitive is the job market, especially for uncertified teachers in private/charter schools? I have heard mixed things - some have told me that schools are begging for computer science teachers, and others have said that though there aren't many teachers, there also aren't many positions, so it is tough to find a job.
I've tried googling this, but it seems tricky to find high school computer science specific advice.

My comment doesn't really address your question about High School, but if you're OK with "older high schoolers" a lot of US technical and community colleges don't require the same teaching certifications that High Schools do and rather prefer a Masters Degree with some industry experience. That might be a good intermediary option if you're open to it. It could give you some teaching experience which could help your future applications to High Schools. Also a lot of colleges offer free courses to their professors/instructors which might be able to cover your teaching certifications.

I can't speak to private or charter, but essentially every state has some form of alternate route to certification, and computer science is a giant in-demand field.  With a CS degree, I don't think you'll have much trouble getting hired in a public school, though you may have to take some night classes or an exam or something to finish out your certification once you have a district willing to sponsor you.
The details of alternate route vary by state, but your hiring school district will be familiar with them.
